# CSS selections stuck

Tags: html, css

How can I select the `<a>` tags that are only inside these divs in CSS?

```
<div id="myDiv">
    <div id="innerDiv1">
        <a href="...">Some Link 1</a>
    </div>
    <div id="innerDiv2">
        <a href="...">Some Link 2</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using id's, instead do something like `class="innerDiv1"`

Comment: Don't use "id" in more than one element. use "class" instead. ID is unique.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to only select `a` tags inside of `innerDiv1` then do this:

```
#innerDiv1 a {
}
```

There is an issue here though, in that you have multiple `id`s. Do not use the same `id` for multiple elements. Instead, use a `class` like so:

```
<div id="myDiv">
    <div class="innerDiv1">
        <a href="...">Some Link 1</a>
</div>
    <div class="innerDiv1">
        <a href="...">Some Link 2</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And then style it like this:

```
.innerDiv1 a {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the child heirarchy as

```
#myDiv #innerDiv1 a {
    /* code here */
}
```

This code would be applied to all of the hyperlinks under the parent with the id myDiv1 and then under innerDiv1 and then it would go to the child element of a to apply the style to it.

But, you can't use a single id for multiple elements. That is invalid in HTML. You can use class Names instead.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can't set the same id for elements on page, change id='innerDiv1' to class='innerDiv1', after that, you can select a tag like this:

```
#myDiv .innerDiv1 a {}
```

Answer (score 1):

The immediate concern is that you have two entities with the same ID. An ID should be unique within the document. The class attribute is better suited to selection of multiple entities:

```
<div id="myDiv">
    <div class="innerDiv1">
        <a href="...">Some Link 1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="innerDiv1">
        <a href="...">Some Link 2</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

... which you can then target using CSS via:

```
div#myDiv div.innerDiv1 a {

}
```

This CSS selector is saying: match all A tags found within DIV tags of class "innerDiv1" which are themselves found within a DIV whose ID is "myDiv"

Answer (score 0):

If you use unique ids as nathan suggested, so propably

```
<div id="myDiv">
    <div id="innerDiv1">
        <a href="...">Some Link 1</a>
    </div>
    <div id="innerDiv2">
        <a href="...">Some Link 2</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

use as CSS

```
#innerDiv1 a,
#innerDiv2 a {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Basically, I have a lot of these inner divs so is there any way to select the 'a' tags in all the child divs of "myDiv". Sorry my question wasn't structured great!

Comment: You could do `#myDiv div a { ... }` or if you want to restrict the rule to direct div children: `#myDiv > div a { ... }`

Comment: That restriction was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone, I kind of made a fool of myself here :S
Basically what is happening is, when I use a class in the inner divs like so:

```html
<div id="myDiv">
    <div class="myLinks">
        <a href="...">Some Link 1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="myLinks">
        <a href="...">Some Link 2</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
myLinks a, a:visited {
    ...
}
myLinks a:hover {
    ...
}
```

this only applies the first styling and does not apply the a:hover one. So how can I choose the 'a' tags as a child of inner divs which is a child of "myDiv".
I hope that made sense.